# php function default argument delivers bool

Tags: php, codeigniter, arguments, parameter-passing

I am using the CodeIgniter 3 framework. I have a validation that calls for a function valid_date which requires 2 parameters. The first is the inputted date from a form (nothing special about it). The second is the format of the date. In general this is d-m-Y.

```php
/**
  * Datum validatie
  * 
  * @param date, format
  * @return controle
  */
public function valid_date($date, $format = 'd-m-Y') 
{
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
  return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
}
```

What I find very strange is that this method is unable to pass the $format on to the rest of the method. When I just declare the variable in the method there is no problem what so ever.

So when I did some test the format was handled like a bool value.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the second parameter gets filled up by the CI_Form_validation as a bool.

So to fix this issue in codeigniter.

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('aanvangDatum','Aanvangs datum','trim|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|valid_date[d-m-Y]');
```

The parameter is the d-m-Y between the []